# Speed typing test

Tags: javascript, httprequest

In this JavaScript code they had 17 test cases, all the 17 test cases two test cases are not comming they are

1. When the reset button is clicked, an HTTP request should be made to get a random quotation from the given URL and the value in the HTML paragraph element with id quoteDisplay should be replaced with quotation received in the response
2. When page is opened, an HTTP request should be made to get a random quotation from the given URL and the HTML paragraph element with id quoteDisplay should have the quotation received in the response.

Please help me

```
let timerEl = document.getElementById("timer");
let speedTypingTestEl = document.getElementById("speedTypingTest");
let quoteDisplayEl = document.getElementById("quoteDisplay");
let quoteInputEl = document.getElementById("quoteInput");
let submitBtnEl = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
let resetBtnEl = document.getElementById("resetBtn");
let spinnerEl = document.getElementById("spinner");

let countdown = 0;

function getQuoteDisplay() {
    let randomUrl = "https://apis.ccbp.in/random-quote";
    let options = {
        method: "GET",
    };

    fetch(randomUrl, options)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData) {
            quoteDisplay(jsonData.content); // use jsonData.content instead
        });
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        countdown = countdown + 1;
        timerEl.textContent = countdown;
    }, 1000);
});
spinnerEl.classList.add("d-none");
for (let result of searchResults) {
    createAndAppendSearchResult(result);
}


function searchWikipedia(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {

        spinnerEl.classList.remove("d-none");
        searchResultsEl.textContent = "";

        let searchInput = quoteInputEl.value;
        let url = "https://apis.ccbp.in/random-quote" + quoteInput;
        let options = {
            method: "GET"
        };

        fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                let {
                    search_results
                } = jsonData;
                displayResults(search_results);
            });
    }
}
resetBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getAllValues();
    var string_a = jsonData.content;
    var string_b = str;
    var n = string_a.localeCompare(string_b);
    var textVal = document.getElementById('quoteInput').value;
    if (n == 1 && textVal == "") {
        clearInterval(cancel);
        feedback.innerText = "You typed in " + seconds + " seconds";
    } else if (n == -1 || textVal == "") {
        feedback.innerText = "You typed incorrect sentence";
    } else {}


});
```

Comment: Can you post HTML code too, so that it will help us to resolve those issues